# download files using Yii2 gridFS

Tags: yii2, gridfs

I want to download files from gridfs using YII2. I am new to Yii I have used this code

```
   class classname extends \path\controller{   
   $connection = new \yii\mongodb\Connection([
        'dsn' => 'mongodb://localhost:27017/files',
    ]);
    $connection->open();
    $fileCollection = new Collection();
    $collection = $connection->getCollection('fs.files');
    $records = $collection->findOne(["_id"=>'548171105e24cfe00c0000ee'],["filename"]);
```

but I have retrived the file details. can anyone please tell me how to proceed further for downloading a file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fileSend() method

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-response.html#sendFile()-detail